# mongo replica set member is fatal

Tags: mongodb, replication

I'm trying to configure a replica set of 3 members on 3 different Linux machines. Im running the mongod with replset in the config file. I mistakley set 'rs.initialize' in 2 machines, and now I have found the primary and tried to add the other instances, but it says that the config file is not from the same version.

How can I remove the replica set and start everything back from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the following is true:

1. Is this a brand-new deployment. 
   There is no data you need to keep.

You can do the following:

1. Shutdown all 3 mongods.
2. Remove all files and directories from the
   "dbpath" partition in all 3 machines
3. Restart all 3 mongods Connect
   to one of the mongodds and submit the following command

   ```
   config = { "_id": "rs0", "members" : [
         { "_id" : 0, "host" : "##Your DNS NAME:PORTNUMBER#" },
         { "_id" : 1, "host" : "##Your DNS NAME:PORTNUMBER#" },
         { "_id" : 2, "host" : "##Your DNS NAME:PORTNUMBER#" } ]
   ```

   }
        rs.initiate(config)